# How to mutate object-values of parent object with Object.values?

Tags: javascript

How can I get references to values of the following object `initial` and mutate filtered objects?

This will not change `initial["w"]` to `13` and I want to achieve this behaviour.

```js
const initial = {
  "q": { a: 1},
  "w": { a: 2},
  "e": { a: 3},
}

// filtering
const filtered = Object.values(initial).filter(v => v.a >= 2);

// mutation
filtered[0].a = 13

console.log(initial)
```

Comment: It does change the value

Comment: @Konrad now that you refactored the question to show that the question is wrong is there any utility to the question? Should I vote close?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This will not change initial["w"] to 13 and I want to achieve this behaviour.

Yes it will

```js
const initial = {
    "q": { a: 1},
    "w": { a: 2},
    "e": { a: 3},
}

// filtering
const filtered = Object.values(initial).filter(v => v.a >= 2);

// mutation
filtered[0].a = 13

console.log(initial.w.a)
```